# Issue with JSX HTMLAttribute setting style for div tag in reactjs react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dom

i am facing issue with the setting style for html div attribute in reactjs without jsx.

I am calculating height for the div from `calculateAvailableHeight()` so that div content is managed with overflow:auto. but unfortunately I cannot set style for div tag.

versions:

```
"react": "^16.6.3",

"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",

"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
```

Here is reactjs code for react component

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {Row,Col,Tab,Nav,NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {calculateAvailableHeight} from './../../lib/uiComponentLib

var heightList = calculateAvailableHeight(50);
var ccUserStyle = {

    height : heightList ,
    overflow:"auto !important",

};
```

**output for heightList : 568px !important**

```
class UserList extends Component{



render(){

    console.log("Reaching inside ", heightList );

    return (

    <div style={ccUserStyle}>
    <Tab.Container   id="sidebarTabContainer" defaultActiveKey="first" >
        <Row className="clearfix">
            <Col sm={12} className="cc-no-padding">
                <Nav bsStyle="pills" justified>
                    <NavItem eventKey="first">User</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey="second">Group</NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={12} className="cc-no-padding" style = height= {heightList} >
            <Tab.Content animation>
                <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">

                Userlist
                </Tab.Pane>

                <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">Group list</Tab.Pane>
            </Tab.Content>
            </Col>
        </Row>  
    </Tab.Container>
    </div>


  );
 }  
}
```

I am using `ccUserStyle object` to set  div style. But after rendering the component i don't see any style attribute for div tag.

Please suggest and help me to rectify this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review your post, fixing the typos and ensuring that the code is an accurate reflection of your real code (the above has at least one significant syntax error, which you can see from the code highlighting, that you probably introduced while copying it to your question, but we cant know that for sure). Please also ensure the code is marked up correctly (note the `}` outside the code block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TJCrowder for the lead, but I resolved the issue by removing "px !important" string from "568px !important".

As react16 are really strict and it avoids any kind of datatype error.

So only Number be initialize with height HttpAttribute JSX in CSSProperties.

this issue is related to only for react16 versions for inline styling.

Please let me know, if you find any other solution for the same.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sir, please confirm my answer on this is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`ccUserStyle` is **already** an object, but this:

```
<div style={{ccUserStyle}}>
```

...wraps it in *another* object (using shorthand property notation), so the style properties don't get found as they're on `style.ccUserStyle.height` instead of `style.height`.

Just remove one layer of `{}`:

```
<div style={ccUserStyle}>
```

Comment: I tried same but its not working at all i cant set JSX HTMLAttribute in react

Comment: really sorry , updated code again. Can you check it once again.